# vim automatic substitution

Tags: vim, editors

I have the following lines:

```
    '0,
    '1,
    '2,
    '3,
```

How to put quote before the comma?

I've tried the following so far:

```
%s/[0-9],/&/g
```

so & here replaces the matched pattern...

Answer (score 7):

You can use something like:

```
%s/\('[0-9]\),/\1',/
```

It uses `\(` and `\)` to create selection group which is then referenced by `\1` (which means first group) on the substitute side.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use macros for tasks like this.

```
qqEi'<Esc>0jq3@q
```

will get the job done (note the `<Esc>` part is an escape key press, not 5 separate keys). Here is a break down:

- `qq` starts recording a macro and assign it to the `q` key.
- `Ei'<Esc>` goes to the end of the word and inserts the `'`.
- `0j` goes to the beginning of the next line.
- `q` ends the recording.
- `3@q` plays the macro 3 times, applying the same thing to the other 3 lines.

Replace `3` with the number of lines that you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **move** the quota from place before the number to a place before the comma, then you can use grouping

```
%s/'\([0-9]\),/\1',/
```

or to put another quotation mark before the comma, just include it into the first group:

```
%s/\('[0-9]\),/\1',/
```

Comment: How is this answer different from Krzysztofs?

Answer (score 1):

```
%s/,$/',/g
```

$ is the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to define the general form where you need this to work. To do just what you asked for without guessing, this is the most simple (lazy!) solution that works for your example input:

```
%s/,/',/
```

If you want to handle more complex cases too, you should write better examples including the most complex case where you need the pattern substitution to work, and ideally an example of the target output too.